# R's Makevars: PKG_CXXFLAGS vs. PKG_CXX11FLAGS

Tags: r, rcpp

When creating an R package with a compiled C++ extension, one can specify the C++ standard and flags to use to compile it in a file `src/Makevars` - for example:

```
CXX_STD = CXX11
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -fmyflag
```

Although the R build system has variables used in compilation such as `CXX` (the C++ compiler) and `PKG_CXXFLAGS` (flags to pass to the C++ compiler), it also has standard-specific flags such as `CXX11`/`CXX14` and `PKG_CXX11FLAGS`/`PKG_CXX14FLAGS`.

The R Extensions Manual does not say much about those other flags, but it does mention that the current default standard is C++11 and thus `CXX` == `CXX11`, and that different compilers might be used for different C++ standards. Some of the notes also mention that `PKG_CXXFLAGS` might in some situations only apply to the default `CXX` compiler.

If I am creating a package in which I define an `src/Makevars` and I specifically require it to compile as C++11:

```
CXX_STD = CXX11
```

Should I specify the flags through `PKG_CXXFLAGS`, or should I use instead `PKG_CXX11FLAGS`, or both? Is is portable/good-practice to use standard-specific flags?

Right now I assume it shouldn't make any difference but the default standard might change in the future and I would want the package to keep working without changes. I see packages such as `RcppArmadillo` have just `PKG_CXXFLAGS`+`CXX_STD`, but if I try adding flags to my user `Makevars`, oftentimes packages would only pick them if they are under `PKG_CXX11FLAGS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just wrong:

```
CXX_STD = CXX11
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -fmyflag
```

as you have a contradiction between the two lines, so you need

```
CXX_STD = CXX11
PKG_CXX11FLAGS = -fmyflag
```

Personally, I never quite understood why we have four of these given that any one package can only ever compile to one standard but .... shrug-emoji-here .... I don't own the R build system either and just play along.  Which works if you play by the rules.